# Get Numeric Filename Suffix for Unix Split

Tags: unix, split

The Unix Split command produces filenames with the suffix aa to zz, there is no way to change the split command, the only way is to change the filenames afterward.
I would like to ask a way to change the suffix aa to zz into 001, 002, ...
Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

```
typeset -i  loopI  
typeset -Z3 newSuf  
typeset -i  numFile  

set -A suf aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az
numFile=`echo ${#suf[*]}`  
numFile=$numFile-1  
fileName=foo  
split -100 $fileName.txt $fileName.  

loopI=0  
cont=y  

while [ $cont = "y" ]; do  
   newSuf=`expr $loopI + 1`  
   mv $fileName.${suf[$loopI]} $fileName.$newSuf  
   loopI=$loopI+1  
   if [ $loopI -le $numFile ]; then  
      if [ ! -f $fileName.${suf[$loopI]} ]; then  
         cont=n  
      fi  
   else  
      cont=n  
   fi  
done
```